# dropdown option showed 2 times in form option while it must not appear

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

The default "select an option" text appear 2 times in the drop-down menu when i use bootstrap-select,
it must not appear when i click the menu to see the option.

screenshot:
http://pastebin.com/iLNtjjcn

html code: http://pastebin.com/ZurpbXAX

how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is the standard way how a dropdown list works.

Your `"select an option"` is actually the first option of your dropdown and it is selected.
Because it is selected you see it "before" the dropdown and you see it in the dropdown because it is a valid option to choose from.

You can delete that option so your first option is "On hold". But then you have the same problem with that option.

Comment: if the first option was "on hold" or any other option how can i get result for this option from database once the page is loaded?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean. But why is the "double option" a problem? Everybody is used to this because it is the way a dropdown works.

Comment: i mean if use "on hold" as the first selected option, how can i display the result for this option once the page is opened? (without need to choose this option since it's already selected by default)

Comment: It is indeed easier to just have a "dummy" value so you can compare this. Otherwise your never 100% sure that the user did choose something.

Comment: ok, anw i think there is a solution to the option not appear 2 times, so till waiting for an answer

Comment: SOLVED: `<option selected disabled style="display:none;">Select an option:</option>`